# Get Drawables out of RelativeLayout or Group Drawables

Tags: android, layout, graphics, view, drawable

what I want to do is as following:
I have a set of Drawables (eg. 16) that I have to combine in different ways (Icon with 1, 2, 3 or 4 Drawables), depending on buisness logic. My idea was to define RelativeLayouts with ImageViews inside. Unfortunately I planned to take these Layouts as an OverlayItem (needs a Drawable) to show them on a MapView. I thought that any Layout is Drawable, but it isn't. I don't find a way to convert this RelativeLayout to a drawable. I really don't get the main difference. Isn't it right that any VIEW can be DRAWN?
Can I group multiple Drawables into one? I'm really a beginner on 2D Graphics and got no clue how to solve this. Any idea appreciated

ADD:
Code Sample based on the first answer:

```
public class MapViewActivity extends MapActivity {

MapView mMapView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

    mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mMapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one_drawable);
    //this is where exception is thrown
    }
}
```

and the file one_drawable.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item 
      android:id="@+id/item_one"
      android:top="0dip"
      android:right="0dip"
      android:bottom="0dip"
      android:left="0dip"/>
</layer-list>
```

So I cannot see any mistake (I set the drawables programatically in my Program)

EDIT 2:
OK I'm not allowed to do that. I have to set up a drawable, which can be exchanged later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in spite of any View could be drawn, it is not a drawable.  You should use [Layer List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)
 to operate several pictures as one drawable.

Comment: Very nice. It seems like that is exactly what I need. I think I can combine LayerDrawable and LevelList to get rid of that ugly ImageFactory i write. I mark this as accepted as soon it works

Comment: I facing some Problems in the usage of it.

Comment: I have defined 4 Layer-List xml and put them into the Drawable folder.
If I call mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one_drawable) I'm getting an java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{[package].MapViewActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/one_drawable.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020003
What am I doing wrong

Comment: I believe you should provide some code samples if you want to receive advise. Also I believe this answer was accepted previously ;)

Comment: its true, but I think I don't get any response anymore if I accept this answer ;) 
should I accept it again, and ask this question seperatly?
Anyway, look at my edit in original post fpr code samples I use

Comment: 1) Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one);

and the file one_drawable.xml looks like this


why drawable names are different (one and one_drawable)?

Comment: 2) You've asked for ideas and accepted the answer, acceptance removal sounds not ok if you not sure in certain implementation. You should read docs properly and ask for another advise ;)

Comment: Ok I'm really Sorry for that. Accepted again! so the Drawable one_ and one_drawable was just a typo in this Forum. 
However I have a solution Now. I looked deep into stack trace and find a message that I HAVE to set a drawable there. I'm NOT allowed to leave it and fill it afterwards programaticaly.